# Angular2, How to get the current active component selector to use it as class globally for css styling

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I want to apply styling for each component, what i am looking is I want to get the current component selector name and pass it as class name like this

```
<div [class]="component-slector-name">
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

so that for every active component I get its selector and set it to div tag for custom css styling..

Does anyone know how to do this ??
Thanks in advance for time and support.

Comment: Why do you want to pass class name? Since, every component has its own name, you can just write styles for your element like this
`component-selector-name {
 // your css rules
}`

Comment: Also, each component can have its own dedicated, isolated CSS rules, though the styles or styleUrls property of its decorator.

Comment: Ya but when i am applying css to its dedicated css file it's not getting applied, and i got link through search regarding the view Encapsulation, on using that the style is getting set globaly. That is throughout application I am settings .container{padding-left:240px} but for login content i want .container{padding-left:0px} , so when i am using ViewEncapsulation the style is getting applied globally.

Comment: Also my app.html is like
<div>
<header></header>
<main>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
<footer></footer>
</div>
now for login component I want to set the {padding-left:0px} for <main ></main> and for whole application i want {padding left:240px}

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host. But again, even with a global stylesheet, you just need `main { ... }`. Adding a class is unnecessary.

Comment: I have added main{pading-left:240px; } to my global stylesheet, but how to set it for the login component as i have even tried ::ng-deep and :host as well as ::host-context(){} nothing works for me. Or i am making some mistake for applying host. So can you help me out in achieving it.... Or can you share the code....

Comment: @ JB Nizet can you share the code or help me to apply the :host ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve it.

Here is one option:

***.html**

```html
<div [class]="activeSelector">
  <router-outlet (activate)="onActivated($event)"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

***.ts**

```typescript
activeSelector: string;

constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

onActivated(component) {
  this.activeSelector = 
        this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(component.constructor).selector;    
}
```

Comment: How to use and get the component resolver selector for lazy modules ?