# Get current Component in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I need to inject css classes based on current component. i.e: if I'm currently on LoginComponent, I need to inject `login` class into the `app.component.html` (the greater parent of my app). Like so:

```
<div class="content login">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I don't know what the best practices are to handle this. I could also based the injection on url. i.e: if url is xxx./login, then inject `login` css class.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47258429/angular2-how-to-get-the-current-active-component-selector-to-use-it-as-class-gl

Answer (score 7):

`<router-outlet>` provides some events like

```
<router-outlet (activate)="currentComponent = $event"></router-outlet>
```

See also https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet

Comment: This works well in dev environments, but if you try to compile, minify and deploy this to a production enviroment it converts all the module names to `n`

Comment: What module names? I'm not working with Angular since a while.

Answer (score 0):

First, make a mother class with a getter like this

```
export class ClassNamer {
  get className() { return this.constructor.name.toLowerCase().replace('component', ''); }
}
```

This will return the class name, to lower case, without the `component` word.

In your classes, you must do

```
export class LoginComponent extends ClassNamer { ... }
```

Now, in your HTML, all you have to do is

```
<div class="{{className}}"></div>
```

Voilà !

**EDIT** If you want to apply the class to the parent component, then in your ClassNamer, add an Output, that emits the className to the parent (but keep in mind that a router outlet isn't a "parent" *per se*)