# How to get the current active component selector for lazy module angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have added current component selector in app.component.ts as per my previous question [Angular2, How to get the current active component selector to use it as class globally for css styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47258429/angular2-how-to-get-the-current-active-component-selector-to-use-it-as-class-gl)

but now i have modified my code to use lazy module functionality, I have only issue of accessing the component selector using the below code

```
 activeSelector: string;

 constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

 onActivated(component) {
 this.activeSelector = 
      this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(component.constructor).selector;    

 }
```

I am getting the below error:

**No component factory found for MyComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?.**

I have tried to add in the entry components and in NgModule even but still don't know how to access it for lazy module.

Does any one know how to achieve it for lazy module. Thank in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you setup demo? You should use ComponentFactoryResolver  from lazy module

Comment: OK. I will do that and give you the Link

Comment: Here is the link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rtp7pg You can check the code in app.component.ts. I want to access the current component as selector in app.component.html as i have applied css based on the selector. When i tried to access the component selector i facing error No component factory found for Component

Comment: Here's workaround https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rtp7pg-r53hby?file=src/app/app.component.ts for the being time

Comment: I am getting this error :                                                                        
     ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
     at AppComponent.onActivated (app.component.ts:77)
     at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (AppComponent.html:15)

Comment: Which version angular are you using?

Comment: I am using angular-cli v4.3.3

Comment: I am getting the constructor when i use this and console.                                     Object.getPrototypeOf(component).constructor but when i do Object.getPrototypeOf(component).constructor['__annotations__'] i am getting undefined console.log

Comment: Because it was changed. Here's the previous version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274539/when-and-how-s-decorator-applied-to-the-decorated-classes-from-the-angular-pack/45276490#45276490 of how to get metadata from component. But it's too ugly for me anyway

Comment: Ok great one it worked. Thanks @yurzui for the help. it saved a lot of time. But i want your suggesstion. what's the best practice should i use this method? wil it effect produciton issues ?? or aot build ? should i migrate to cli v.5 to use the latest methods like the pne you defined in stacckblitz?

Comment: Here's another option https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rtp7pg-39hsz9?file=src/app/app.component.ts You can get tagName directly

Comment: Thanks yurzui. But this is again breaking. @tagName. But previous code works fine, NextElementSiblings is returning me as undefined

Comment: Maybe the best approach that will absolute work with Jit and AOT is to create key (like `cssClass`) on your component https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rtp7pg-cwjxaa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: This is better option. Easy and quite better. Thanks great one again @yurzui. Great knowledge !!!